# Flutter remove specific RouteSettings settings value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I want to remove specific route in the route settings. I don't want the page to navigate from the current page. just want to remove specific route. or making the arguments null, once the arguments values are assigned to a variable.

I tried below navigator, but it's navigating to previous screens

> Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(
> builder: (context) => LoginScreen()), (Route route) => false);
>
> Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);

Please help me

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want. Do you want to remove all under pages from stack after you pushed a new page and user can’t pop to previous screen?

Comment: I am passing route arguments as below. I just want to use this value for other purposes. after i consume the value i want to remove the route or remove arugments from the route settings. so second time it wont have any values and do someother operations. navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed('/someRoute', arguments: notify(loggedInUserKey: messageMap["sender"], requestorUserKey: messageMap["receiver"]));

Comment: In short just want to remove specific route without navigation from the current page.